# Super-gradients; yolo-nas Error after first Validation run: "'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 20-22: character maps to <undefined>"

Tags: yolo, roboflow

I have the following versions installed:

- torch: 1.13.1
- super-gradients: 3.1.2

I got the following training parameters:

```
from super_gradients.training.losses import PPYoloELoss
from super_gradients.training.metrics import DetectionMetrics_050
from super_gradients.training.metrics import DetectionMetrics_050_095

from super_gradients.training.models.detection_models.pp_yolo_e import PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback



train_params = {
    'silent_mode': False,
    "average_best_models":True,
    "warmup_mode": "linear_epoch_step",
    "warmup_initial_lr": 1e-6,
    "lr_warmup_epochs": 3,
    "initial_lr": 5e-4,
    "lr_mode": "cosine",
    "cosine_final_lr_ratio": 0.1,
    "optimizer": "Adam",
    "optimizer_params": {"weight_decay": 0.0001},
    "zero_weight_decay_on_bias_and_bn": True,
    "ema": True,
    "ema_params": {"decay": 0.9, "decay_type": "threshold"},
    "max_epochs": EPOCHS,
    "mixed_precision": True,
    "loss": PPYoloELoss(
        use_static_assigner=False,
        num_classes=len(dataset_params['classes']),
        reg_max=16
    ),
    "valid_metrics_list": [
        DetectionMetrics_050(
            score_thres=0.1,
            top_k_predictions=300,
            num_cls=len(dataset_params['classes']),
            normalize_targets=True,
            post_prediction_callback=PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback(
                score_threshold=0.01,
                nms_top_k=1000,
                max_predictions=300,
                nms_threshold=0.7
            )
        ),
        DetectionMetrics_050_095(
            score_thres=0.1,
            top_k_predictions=300,
            num_cls=len(dataset_params['classes']),
            normalize_targets=True,
            post_prediction_callback=PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback(
                score_threshold=0.01,
                nms_top_k=1000,
                max_predictions=300,
                nms_threshold=0.7
            )
        )
    ],
    "metric_to_watch": 'mAP@0.50:0.95'
}
```

`

and the follwong traingin process:

```
models_to_train = ['yolo_nas_s']
 
CHECKPOINT_DIR = 'checkpoints'
 
trainer = Trainer(
    experiment_name='yolo_nas_s', 
    ckpt_root_dir=CHECKPOINT_DIR
)

model = models.get(
    'yolo_nas_s', 
    num_classes=len(dataset_params['classes']), 
    pretrained_weights="coco"
)

trainer.train(
    model, 
    training_params=train_params, 
    train_loader=train_data, 
    valid_loader=val_data
)
```

After the first validation run I get following error:
"'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 20-22: character maps to "

Can anyone help?

Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuwcw.png)

I tried to train a yolo-nas model on customized data.

Answer (score 0):

```
train_params = {
'silent_mode': False, --> change it to 'silent_mode': True,
```

The training procedure is producing no displaying results; however, you can observe it in your checkpoints path.

[image: log file of training procedure]

[image: Example in the train_params configuration]